# How to access multiple files in multiple folders in the same directory using fs.readdir?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to list the files contained in different folders (all these folders are in the same directory). So what I thought to do was this:

```
fs.readdir(unzippedPath, (err, folders) => {
  folders.forEach((folder) => {
    console.log(`${unzippedPath}/${folder}/`); // all good till here

    fs.readdir(`${unzippedPath}/${folder}}/`, (err, files) => {
      console.log('files: ', files);
    });
  });
});
```

First read all the folders inside the main directory (unzippedPath) then for each of those folders read the files in them.
While the first log print what the directory of the right folder, the second log returns undefined.
While the direcoty logged is correct, I do not understand why it doesn't log the files for each folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have a typo. You have one `}` more in the first parameter of the nested `fs.readdir`.

`${unzippedPath}/${folder}}/` should be `${unzippedPath}/${folder}/`.

Comment: Heh, no worries, glad I could help